# How to get the OpenWith list from the Registry?

Tags: registry, open-with

This Windows Registry Key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts
```

...supposedly contains the file extensions registered with Windows Explorer.

I try to programmatically read the **OpenWith** list for specific file extensions.

So I started with the **.RES** file extension: This key supposedly should contain the OpenWith list for the .res extension:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\\.res\OpenWithList
```

This is how it looks in the Registry:

[image]

However, the OpenWith list for .res files in Windows Explorer looks completely different:

[image]

So how can I get the real OpenWith list for a specific file extension from the Registry?

Windows 7 x64 SP1

Comment: I think you can find solution in this page: [How to associate a file extension to a program without making it the default program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956122/how-to-associate-a-file-extension-to-a-program-without-making-it-the-default-pro)

Answer (score 0):

```
key HKLM/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/App Paths/<progname>: "" = <appPath>

key HKCR/Applications/<progname>/SupportedTypes: <fileExt> = ""
key HKCR/<fileExt>: "" = <progID>

key HKCR/<progID>/OpenWithList/<progName>
key HKCR/<fileExt>/OpenWithList/<progName>
key HKCR/SystemFileAssociations/<fileExt>/OpenWithList/<progName>
```

Delete key and subkey at:

```
HKCU/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Explorer/fileExts/<fileExt>
```

This key form [How to associate a file extension to a program without making it the default program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956122/how-to-associate-a-file-extension-to-a-program-without-making-it-the-default-pro)